# Proof that the equation has infinitely many complex solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I proof that the equation $$\exp(10z^2)+a\cdot \exp(6z^2)+b\cdot \exp(3z^2)=2019$$ has infinitely many complex solutions when $a$ and $b$ are two given complex numbers? 
My idea is to find one solution because of the $2\pi$-periodicity but I think this is very difficult.

Thank You :)

Comment: Is this a challenge/contest question?

Comment: Show work. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Hint: if $w = \exp(z^2)$ this can be written as $w^{10} + a w^6 + b w^3 = 2019$.

Comment: Okay, if I write it as $w^{10}+a\cdot w^6+b\cdot w^3=2019$ I get an polynomial and by the fundamental theorem of algebra a solution $w$ exists, right? And now, because of $\exp(z^2+2k\pi i)=\exp(z^2)=w$, I know that there are infinetly many complex solutions. 

It would be very cool if this is correct but it sounds a bit to easy.

Comment: @alpaka123 that is exactly the right idea.